# "internal compiler exception occurred" while using gxt grid

Tags: java, grid, gxt

> I AM USING GWT 2.5.1 AND GXT 2.2.5,
>   THIS IS THE BEAN I AM USING:

```
public class Modelo extends BaseModel {

public Modelo(String nombre,String noParte,String imagen){
    this.set("nombre", nombre);
    this.set("noParte", noParte);
    this.set("path", imagen);
}

public String getNombre(){
    return (String)get("nombre");
}

public String getNoParte(){
    return (String)get("noParte");
}
public String getPath(){
    return (String)this.get("path");
}
```

}

> //// THIS IS THE DATA I M WORKING WITH:

```
public class Lista {

public static List<Modelo> getList() {
    List<Modelo> datos = new ArrayList<Modelo>();
    datos.add(new Modelo("bomba wp", "3234343","selyR.jpg"));
    datos.add(new Modelo("bomba maytag", "343544323","selyR.jpg"));
    datos.add(new Modelo("cople wp", "12323","selyR.jpg"));        
    datos.add(new Modelo("perros wp", "545563","selyR.jpg"));
    datos.add(new Modelo("bobinas secadora wp","534532","selyR.jpg"));
    datos.add(new Modelo("banda maytag","3123123","selyR.jpg"));
    return datos;
}
```

}

> ////// THIS IS THE WINDOW CONFIGURATION

```
public class Carrito extends Window {

public Carrito(String nombre1) {

    this.setHeading(nombre1);
    this.setWidth(900);
    this.setHeight(600);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLayout(new FitLayout());

}

@Override
protected void onRender(Element parent, int pos) {
    super.onRender(parent, pos);

    List<ColumnConfig> configs = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig>();

    ColumnConfig column = new ColumnConfig();
    column.setId("nombre");
    column.setHeader("Nombre Producto");
    column.setWidth(200);
    configs.add(column);

    ColumnConfig column1 = new ColumnConfig();
    column.setId("noParte");
    column.setHeader("# parte");
    column.setWidth(200);
    configs.add(column1);

    ColumnConfig column2 = new ColumnConfig();
    column.setId("path");
    column.setHeader("imagen");
    column.setWidth(200);
    configs.add(column2);

    ListStore<Modelo> listaPiezas = new ListStore<Modelo>();
    listaPiezas.add(Lista.getList());

    ColumnModel cm = new ColumnModel(configs);
    Grid<Modelo> grid = new Grid<Modelo>(listaPiezas, cm);
    //grid.setStyleAttribute("borderTop", "none");
    //grid.setAutoExpandColumn("name");
    grid.setBorders(true);
    grid.setStripeRows(true);

    ContentPanel cp = new ContentPanel();
    cp.setBodyBorder(false);
    cp.setHeading("Carrito");
    cp.setButtonAlign(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    cp.setLayout(new FitLayout());
    cp.setSize(900, 600);
    cp.add(grid);

    this.add(cp);


}
```

}

> //// THIS IS THE ERROR I AM GETTING:
>
> ```
>          [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
> com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit.
> ```
>
> at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.translateException(JVisitor.java:109)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:276)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:116)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation.traverse(JCastOperation.java:65)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:116)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBinaryOperation.traverse(JBinaryOperation.java:81)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:116)
>     at        >com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JExpressionStatement.traverse(JExpressionStatement.java:41)
>     at   >com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContextImmutable.traverse(JModVisitor.java:170)
>     at >com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemoveImmutable(JModVisitor.java:33>6)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:83)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:137)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:133)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:82)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:434)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.traverse(JMethod.java:403)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.mainLoop(UnifyAst.java:900)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.exec(UnifyAst.java:625)
>     at >com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:6>40)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:33)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:278)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:141)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
>     at >com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface >com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType, but class was expected
>     at >com.extjs.gxt.ui.rebind.core.TemplatesGenerator$SourceGenerator.validateType(TemplatesGene>rator.java:142)
>     at >com.extjs.gxt.ui.rebind.core.TemplatesGenerator$SourceGenerator.generate(TemplatesGenerato>r.java:97)
>     at >com.extjs.gxt.ui.rebind.core.TemplatesGenerator.generate(TemplatesGenerator.java:56)
>     at >com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator>.java:40)
>     at >com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGenera>torContext.java:657)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
>     at >com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:79>)
>     at >com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:276)
>     at >com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:265)
>     at >com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerR>ebindPermutationOracle.java:91)
>     at >com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleGwtCreate(UnifyAst.java:355)
>     at >com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleMagicMethodCall(UnifyAst.java:433)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.endVisit(UnifyAst.java:237)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:243)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
>     ... 42 more
>        [ERROR] at GridView.java(1362): GWT.create(GridTemplates.class)
>          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall
>        [ERROR] at GridView.java(1362): (GridTemplates) GWT.create(GridTemplates.class)
>           com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation
>        [ERROR] at GridView.java(1362): this.templates = (GridTemplates) >GWT.create(GridTemplates.class)
>           com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBinaryOperation
>        [ERROR] at GridView.java(1362): this.templates = (GridTemplates)    >GWT.create(GridTemplates.class)
>           com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JExpressionStatement
>        [ERROR] at GridView.java(1361): {
>    this.templates = (GridTemplates) GWT.create(GridTemplates.class);
>   }
>           com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock
>        [ERROR] at GridView.java(1361): {
>       this.templates = (GridTemplates) GWT.create(GridTemplates.class);
>       }
>           com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody
>        [ERROR] at GridView.java(1361): protected void initTemplates();
>
> ```
>     com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod
>  C:\Users\NORE\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ventas\nbproject\build-gwt.xml:330: >The     following error occurred while executing this line:
> C:\Users\NORE\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ventas\nbproject\build-gwt.xml:479: Java   >returned: 1
> ```

Comment: Why are you screaming? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone runs into this problem.
Make sure you're using gxt-2.3.0-**gwt22**.jar library not gxt-2.3.0-**gwt2**.jar with gwt 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem, after replacing gxt-2.2.5-gwt22 with **gxt-2.2.5-gwt17** it is working fine now.